# Selenium Chrome browser instane not dying in task manager

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, testng, taskmanager

I am Using Selenium as framework in which i have multiple test cases.

I am Using Chrome browser for running the testscripts and used java as language.

I have used TestNG as Framework for running multiple testscripts.

Problem: As soon as 1 TestCase completes execution the chrome driver gets closed and new driver opens up .But in task manager the chromedriver still exists. And i am getting error like

```
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1
```

What i have done : I tried using driver.manage.deleteallcookies() , but the problem does not get solved.

So how can i close this chromedriver32 in Task Manager while running.

Comment: do you specifically call driver.close() in the @afterclass of your test (or whatever it is in testng)?

Comment: no i user driver.quit() , to ensure the instance gets killed.

Answer (score 0):

In last of test script which closing mechanism you have tried,like

```
Webdriver.Close()
Webdriver.Quit()
Webdriver.Dispose()
```

use Webdriver.Quit() for closing driver instance.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the reply, I user driver.quit , but still the error"org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process" is coming after another chrome browser gets opened.

Comment: Please share some code style of your script,or atleast structuere where you initialized and quitting it,it will help to clear the root cause.If you have already solved it,so please share.